# Using variables in the lambda

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I am using Linq to filter some things and some times I need to use reflection to get the value. Here is the example:

```
//...
PropertyType[] properties = myType.GetProperties();
var filtered = properties.Where(p=>p.PropertyType==typeof(MyMetaData) 
&& ((MyType)p.GetValue(obj)).Name=="name"
&& ((MyType)p.GetValue(obj)).Length==10
).ToList();
//...
```

In my example I am using GetValue() method more than one time. Is there way if I can use variable to store it? I think that will help with performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like following should work with [method expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)*(lambda syntax)*

```
    var filtered = properties.Where(p => 
        {
            if(!p.PropertyType is MyMetaData)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var item = (MyType) p.GetValue(obj);
            return item.Name == "name"
                && item.Length == 10
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: I modified your code and that works. I am not sure if it is efficient.

Comment: @Dilshod, You can add the condition in the final clause like `return !p.PropertyType is MyMetaData && item.Name == "name" && ...`, It would be same as above but would be more readable IMO.

Comment: it was like that before, but it is trying to typecast before it filter the properties. There are some properties that can't be cast to MyType. Thats why I am trying to see if the type is MyMetaData before I cast.

Comment: @Dilshod, since you are using `&&`, that will cause the short-circuit and if the first condition resolves to false it will not move further.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like that to include some `variable` in a `LINQ` we have to use the `expression query`, not `method query`, like this:

```
var filtered = (from x in properties
               let a = (x.PropertyType is MyType) ? (MyType) x.GetValue(obj) : null
               where a != null && a.Name == "name" && a.Length == 10).ToList();
```

I think this also works for `method query` with some `Select`:

```
var filtered = properties.Select(p=> new {p, a = (p.PropertyType is MyType) ? (MyType) p.GetValue(obj) : null})
                         .Where(x=>x.a != null && x.a.Name == "name" && x.a.Length == 10)
                         .Select(x=>x.p).ToList();
```

Comment: It is possible to do the same in lambda syntax. Effectively, the let syntax is equivalent to a `Select(x => new { a, x})`. It's just more verbose.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I've edited with the work around in `method style` before reading your comment, thanks.

Comment: @KingKing I am having some trouble with running the query you gave. It is casting to MyType before it filter the properties by MyMetadata type. It is failing because of there are some other properties can't be cast to MyType.